# How to set a locally-provided custom context with Ruby JSON-LD?

Tags: ruby, rdf, semantic-web, json-ld, linked-data

I am getting accustomed to the [Ruby RDF JSON-LD toolset](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/json-ld) and currently I'm trying to extract knowledge from plain JSON files which do not carry a JSON-LD context. Therefore I need a way to set a locally-provided context when loading them.

So what I am doing is using `JSON::LD::API.toRdf`. But it seems I can't set a local context directly in its interface. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON-LD API (Spec and Ruby) describes a [`expandContext` option](http://rdf.greggkellogg.net/yard/JSON/LD/API.html#toRdf-class_method). In Ruby, this can take a string (interpreted as a URL), a something that responds to `#read` (such as a StringIO or File), a `Hash`, `Array`, or an instance of `JSON::LD::Context`.

Typically, if you want to pass a locally-provided context, you can do so as a Hash. A common pattern I use is the following:

```rb
context = JSON.parse(%({
  "@context": {...}
}))

graph = RDF::Graph.new

JSON::LD::API.toRdf(input, context) { |statement| graph << statement}
```

Have a look at the documentation [here](http://rdf.greggkellogg.net/yard/JSON/LD/API.html), or feel free to find me on [gitter](https://gitter.im/ruby-rdf/rdf?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge).

Comment: Sadly, when I do as you described I get the following error when calling `toRdf`: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)`. I am using the most recet `json-ld` gem version 3.1.5.

Comment: I managed to do it now, but I had to use `JSON::LD::API.toRdf(input, expandContext: context) do |statement|` and the context needed to be defined directly in the `context` variable instead of nested within a `"@context" => {…}` member. Am I doing something wrong because your described way didn't work?

Comment: No, I think you have that right. Arguably, the code should look for `@context` and use that, rather than a de-referenced context. We're outside the bounds of the spec here, so it's something entirely defined by the Ruby library. If something's still not working for you, file an issue at https://github.com/ruby-rdf/json-ld/issues.